# Redirect route from index.php?id={id} to /index/{slug}

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-routing

I convert an old project to laravel and I want to create some 301 route to redirect old url.

old url: example.com/index.php?id={id}

new url: example.com/index/{slug}

I try with something like:

```
Route::get('index.php?id={id}', function($id){
    $slug = {where I select slug from id}
    return Redirect::to('/index/'.$slug, 301);
});
```

But It doesn't works, **the url is not recognized.**

Comment: what do u mean by {query} ??
you Mean id which is being passed ?

Comment: the query to grab slug var

Comment: did not get you .

Comment: It's not relevant, the problem is that the url is not recognized, not the query I use to get the slug variable passing the id

Comment: what is the error

Comment: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going about this slightly wrong, you dont need a route for this but a middleware instead.

`php artisan make:middleware Redirect`

```
public function handle( $request, Closure $next )
{
    if( preg_match( '#index.php\?id=(\d+)#is', $request->fullurl(), $matches ) ) {
        return redirect()->to( "/index/{$matches[1]}", 301 );
    }
    return $next( $request );
}
```

add the middleware to the Http Kernel

Comment: in protected $middleware?

Comment: I set as best answer but regex not work on my case I had to change to:
        if( preg_match( '/index.php\?id=(\d+)/', $request->fullurl(), $matches ) ) { (THANKS!)

Comment: I didn't have the time to test. I've updated the answer, regards.